# How to build a tool to enter and access data on cloud

Tags: joomla, cloud

I am a web  designer with no coding experience . I was offered a project. .. the client wants a "tool to put all his data(huge employee records) on cloud and to access it as needed " .My question is

1. What exactly such a tool is called ?
2. Can it be built without coding? Websites like joomla, etc.  Can they be used somehow ?
3. Can coding be learnt simultaneously with the project?

Sorry for the silly question.

Answer (score 0):

We need a little more information. Is the employee data stored in a database? What type of database is it? When you say cloud what do you mean? AWS?

You might be able to create SQL queries without learning SQL using tools like mysqlworkbench but what you would do with that data after the query I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time out to answer . . I don't know any cloud service . What I know is a little bit about the project . ..... I am asked to create a cloud platform to save details of all the employees and to be able to access them whenever needed.  The whole idea sounded like a simple database to me till he bowled me over  with the whole "I want a cloud " thing .